# ¿Cómo crear elemento con aspect ratio 1:1?

Tags: css, css3

Pues eso, busco alguna manera de crear tres elementos horizontales con un aspect ratio de 1:1.

Hago énfasis en que agregar la misma cantidad de píxeles al width y al height no es la respuesta a mi pregunta puesto que a medida que añadas contenedores horizontales, tienes que cambiar el código. Eso solo hace el código sucio, inútil y para nada responsive.

Os pongo un ejemplo de lo que busco:

```css
section {
 display: flex
}

.a {
 background: red
}

.b {
 background: green
}

.c {
 background: blue
}

.a, .b, .c {
 height: 100px; /* ¿qué valor agregar aquí? */
 width: calc(100%/3)
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="c"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Dándole al contenedor los mismos píxeles de alto que de ancho.

Comment: Sí, existen varias maneras, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @phpMyGuel, si quieres crear contenedores horizontales con el mismo alto que ancho, no puedes pretender simplemente ponerle los mismos píxeles porque primero, no está siendo responsive y segundo, si quieres añadir otro contenedor horizontal tienes que modificar el estilo de cada uno de los contenedores.

Comment: @JheymanMejia, pues lo primero que se me vino a la cabeza fue utilizar la propiedad width: calc(100%/3) pero al agregar posteriormente height: calc(100%/3), me saca el cálculo de otro contenedor, no dando un aspect ratio de 1:1.

Comment: @ortiz como comprenderás, con tu pregunta de "Necesito un contenedor que contenga tres elementos horizontales con aspect ratio 1:1" había mucho lugar para la interpretación. La próxima vez trata de ser más específico desde un principio y tendrás respuestas más acordes a lo que necesitas. Un saludo.

Comment: @phpMyGuel No sé qué no has entendido de aspect ratio 1:1 de tres elementos dentro de un contenedor. Un saludo.

Comment: Se entendió perfectamente. Y yo te di una solución que consigue lo que pediste. Si ya quieres que sea responsive, si en vez de tres contenedores en línea puede que haya más o puede haber también menos y sin adjuntar nada de código que oriente pues quizá deberías haberlo plasmado en tu pregunta desde un principio porque a lo mejor el que trata de responderte se ha quedado sin pilas en su bola de cristal. Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando uno habla de aspect ratio se refiere directamente a la **medida proporcional entre ancho y alto**, luego obvias que sea responsive. Le recomiendo que solo responda aquello que entiende y deje cola para los que puedan dar una respuesta adecuada. Reportado por condescendiente y gracioso. Le recomiendo también echarle un ojo a los [Códigos de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Y yo te recomiendo que para dejar de recibir votos de cierre en tus preguntas y que empieces a obtener respuestas que te sean útiles, redactes con el mayor lujo de detalle y claridad lo que pretendes conseguir y que adjuntes a ser posible código o algo que respalde que has investigado antes. Tu pregunta inicial se alejaba mucho de lo que esta comunidad considera una buena pregunta. Y gracias por remitirme el código de conducta, lo conozco y no creo lo haya faltado. Un saludo :)

Comment: El ejemplo que pones no es [aspect ratio 1:1](https://www.figma.com/dictionary/aspect-ratio/), para meter *cuadritos* de forma horizontal y que sea *responsive* necesitarás mucho cálculo y trucos CSS o JS. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que la pregunta, después de sus ediciones, aporta datos suficientes para poder dasarrollar una respuesta adecuada. Aquí subo mi solución:

La magia la aportan dos cosas:

- Uso de `display: grid`.
- Uso del *pseudoelemento* `::before`.

Con `display-grid` y a través de la propiedad `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` podemos establecer que los elementos de nuestro contenedor se distribuyan de tal manera que formen 3 columnas del mismo tamaño y a través de `padding-bottom: 100%` en el `::before` conseguimos que cada columna tenga la misma altura que anchura.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.container div::before {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tres-elementos {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.tres-elementos div {
  background-color: red;
}

.cuatro-elementos {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.cuatro-elementos div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Con tres elementos</p>
<div class="container tres-elementos">
  <div>Elemento 1</div>
  <div>Elemento 2</div>
  <div>Elemento 3</div>
</div>

<p>Con cuatro elementos</p>
<div class="container cuatro-elementos">
  <div>Elemento 1</div>
  <div>Elemento 2</div>
  <div>Elemento 3</div>
  <div>Elemento 4</div>
</div>
```

De esta manera, si quisieras crear un contenedor que albergase 5 columnas lo único que tendrías que hacer sería crear una clase con la propiedad `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` y añadírsela a dicho contenedor (además de el `<div>` adicional para la quinta columna).

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo la solución que buscaba.